# Checking out a file from CVS repository

Tags: linux, repository, cvs, fedora-20

I am trying to get a copy of some files from a repository and am having an issue with the last command they have listed on the website. Here is the commands they gave me.

```
$ touch .cvspass
$ echo "/1 :pserver:coralcvs@opencoral.mit.edu:2401/usr/local/coral-repository Atth0 y'tt" >> .cvspass
$ cvs -d :pserver:coralcvs@opencoral.mit.edu:/usr/local/coral-repository checkout -r <tag> opencoral
```

The issue I am having is with the  part of the last command. I keep getting an error that says:

```
bash: tag: No such file or directory
```

I am probably doing something incorrectly but I have tried looking at guides on how to use CVS commands and I am still confused. Could someone offer some assistance?

Also, I am running Fedora 20.

Comment: Do you really want to use cvs?  I would be tempted to use git-cvs to pull in the full repository.  Then use git commands.

Answer (score 0):

`<tag>` is not supposed to be taken literally, it is a placeholder.  This should be pretty self-evident reading the first paragraph under `Download Source from the CVS Repository` of the instructions on [downloading OpenCoral from CVS](https://opencoral.mit.edu/doc/coral/download.html).

Comment: I tried replacing <tag> with coral-3_4_8. Could you please give an example?

Comment: coral-3_4_8 works fine for me.  `cvs -d :pserver:coralcvs@opencoral.mit.edu:/usr/local/coral-repository checkout -r coral-3_4_8 opencoral`